# Mapping between Notations

Tags: reference-request, ordinal-numbers

As in my other question, it is assumed that the (total) function describing a given notation is denoted as $address:p\rightarrow \Bbb{N}$ and assumed to be bijective.

Suppose we are given two notations $N_1$ and $N_2$ for some $p \in \omega{_C}{_K}$(Church-Kleene). Denote the mapping from $N_1$ to $N_2$ as $P{_1}{_2}:\Bbb{N} \rightarrow \Bbb{N}$.

If we wanted to be more formal, we could say that consider the two functions $address1:p\rightarrow \Bbb{N}$ and $address2:p\rightarrow \Bbb{N}$ corresponding to $N_1$ and $N_2$ respectively. Then $P{_1}{_2}$ is defined by:
$$P{_1}{_2}(address1(x))=address2(x) \qquad for \; all \; x < p$$

Now assume that the less-than relations corresponding to $N_1$ and $N_2$ are computable. My question simply is the following: Is the function $P{_1}{_2}$ always Total-computable? That is, computable using an oracle-program that has access to the set representing "indexes of total recursive functions".

If no, then what would be the example for it (also generally, what would be the suitable upper-bound in that case). If yes, then can someone give a reference where a complete or partial proof(if there is one) for a reasonable upper-bound(or lack of it) is provided.

P.S.
I posted this question on Math.SE (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2380838/mapping-between-notations). After no replies/comments since few days after posting it, I am posting it here. Hopefully that isn't a problem.

Comment: I suspect the lack of answers may be because the presentation is a bit unclear — all the setup of "notations" is really tangential to the main question itself. The question can be given in a single sentence: given two computable well-orderings on $\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}\N$ which happen to have the same order-type, is the induced automorphism of $\N$ computable?

Comment: Your question is very confusingly worded, but I think what you want to ask is this: “let $<_1$ and $<_2$ be two computable well-orders on $\mathbb{N}$ representing the same (computable) ordinal: is it true that the unique isomorphism between them belongs to the Turing degree $\mathbf{0}''$ (of indexes of total recursive functions)?”  Correct?  If this is indeed what you want to ask, I suggest you write it roughly as I just did.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine I think OP wants to know whether the isomorphism belongs to $\mathbf{0}''$ (the use of the phrase "Total-computable" refers to this, I think).

Comment: @Gro-Tsen Well yes, I meant the functions that are computable given the access to oracle representing "indexes of total recursive functions". And if that doesn't suffice, what would be appropriate upper-bound on complexity. Sorry for slightly confusing wording.

Comment: My (rough) guess that some kind of simple upper bound on complexity should exist, stems from the fact that if the well-orderings corresponding to $N_1$ and $N_2$ are computable then we have the following fact: "If $P{_1}{_2}$ and $P{_2}{_1}$ are recursively bounded then $P{_1}{_2}$ is recursive." So I "think" it "seems" to me to break the bound of TOTAL-computable for isomorphism you would also have to break the bound of "busy beaver" for the corresponding oracle-program. And so on for more complex sets in arithmetic hierarchy. I would find it interesting to see how it would be done.

Comment: Perhaps the comment about strictly breaking bound of corresponding "busy beaver" is not quite correct. As I have read that there exist functions which are recursively unbounded but can't be used to calculate $BB$ (and probably then these kind of functions would also exist for higher analogues of $BB$ in arithmetic hierarchy). But whether these kinds of functions can be used in $P{_1}{_2}$, I don't have any idea. I guess I am confusing things more than necessary at this point. TOTAL-computably bounded might be better and more accurate to say perhaps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question is about the oracle strength needed to compute an
isomorphism between two isomorphic computable well-orders. In
general, $0''$ is not necessarily enough to compute such an isomorphism, unless the order-types are sufficiently small, and the general
phenomenon is that the strength needed to compute the isomorphisms rises with the length of the order types being considered.

Let's begin by pointing out what various oracles can compute about a computable well-order relation.

**Theorem.** Suppose that $\langle\mathbb{N},\lhd\rangle$ is a
computable well-order relation.

1. Oracle $0'$ can compute the adjacency relation.
2. Oracle $0''$ can identify limit ordinal nodes.
3. Oracle $0'''$ can compute the "next limit" relation, i.e. where $a\lhd b$ and $b$ is a limit, with no limits between.
4. Oracle $0''''$ can identify limits-of-limits.
5. Oracle $0^{(5)}$ can compute the next-limit-of-limits.

**Proof.** Given $a\lhd b$, the oracle $0'$ can tell if we'll ever
find $c$ such that $a\lhd c\lhd b$ and thereby know whether or not
$a$ and $b$ are adjacent.

Node $b$ is a limit ordinal node, if every $a\lhd b$ does have such
a $c$ between, and this is a $\Pi_2$ question to which $0''$ knows
the answer. So oracle $0''$ can identify the limit ordinal nodes.

Similarly, $b$ is the next limit after $a$, if $a\lhd b$ and every
$c$ between them has a predecessor, which is a $\Pi_3$ question
that $0'''$ can answer. So $0'''$ can compute the next-limit
relation.

A node $b$ is a limit-of-limits, if every smaller node has another
limit node between. This is a $\pi_4$ assertion that $0''''$ can
answer.

And so on. $\Box$

We can use this to find upper bounds on the strength needed to compute
isomorphisms for various small order-types.

**Corollary.**

1. For any two computable well-orders of the same order-type less
   than $\omega^2$, oracle $0'$ can compute the isomorphism.
2. For any two computable well-orders of the same order-type less
   than $\omega^3$, oracle $0'''$ can compute the isomorphism.
3. For any two computable well-orders of the same order-type less
   than $\omega^4$, oracle $0^{(5)}$ can compute the isomorphism.

**Proof.** If the orders have type less than $\omega^2$, then they
have only finitely many limit ordinal nodes, which can be
hard-coded into the program. And then the rest of the isomorphism
amounts to finding adjacencies, which can be computed from $0'$.

If the orders have type less than $\omega^3$, then they have at
most finitely many limits-of-limits, which can be hard-coded into
the program. And the rest of the isomorphism amounts to finding the
next-limit and the corresponding adjacencies, which can be computed
from $0'''$.

And so on. $\Box$

Meanwhile, we can show that for certain small order-types, one does in fact need strength.

**Theorem.**
 There are two computable order relations on $\mathbb{N}$ of order type $\omega$, with no
 computable isomorphism.

**Proof.** Let the first order be the natural numbers with the
usual ordering $\langle\mathbb{N},<\rangle$, which has order type
$\omega$. Let the second order be constructed in the following
computable manner. Put the Turing machines in order in type
$\omega$ and for each machine $p$, create two points $a_p$ and
$b_p$ and specify $a_p<b_p$. Now, begin simulating all programs,
and whenever a new program halts, add a new point $c_p$ with
$a_p<c_p<b_p$. This specifies a computable order with order type
$\omega$. But there can be no computable isomorphism between this
order and the first order, because if there were, we could
computably determine whether or not $b_p$ was a successor of $a_p$
or not, and thereby computable solve the halting problem, which is
impossible. $\Box$

**Theorem.** There are two computable relations with order-type
$\omega^2$, having no $0'$-computable isomorphism relation.

**Proof.** Let the first order of type $\omega^2$ be a computable
ordering for which the map $(n,k)\mapsto\omega\cdot n+k$ is
computable. We build the second order by the following computable
procedure. Order the Turing machines $p$ in order type $\omega$.
Create an interval in our new order associated with each $p$. The
interval will either be finite or infinite (but infinitely many of
them will be infinite, and so the order overall will have type
$\omega^2$). We simulate all programs on input $0$, input $1$,
input $2$ and so on. Every time a program halts on the next input,
we add another point to its interval block. Thus, the total
programs will lead to infinite intervals, but the non-total
programs will lead to finite intervals, since they will be waiting
for their next input to halt. There can be no $0'$-computable
isomorphism from the first order to the second, since from any such
isomorphism, we could tell whether or not an interval was infinite
or not, and thereby come to solve the $\Pi_2$-complete problem of
totality, which is not possible using only $0'$ as an oracle.
$\Box$

**Theorem.** There are two computable relations with order-type
$\omega^3$, having no $0''$-computable isomorphism relation.

**Proof.** For the first order, we can use a standard ordinal
denotation for which the function $(n,m,k)\mapsto
\omega^2\cdot n+\omega\cdot m+k$ is computable. We build the second order by
the following computable procedure. Consider any complete
$\Sigma_3$ relation $A(w)\iff
\exists x\forall y\exists z\ R(w,x,y,z)$, where $R$ is $\Delta_0$.
We may assume that infinitely many $w$ have such an $x$, that every
$(w,x)$ has infinitely many $y$ with some $z$ for which
$R(w,x,y,z)$, and that when there is an $x$ for $w$, then there are
infinitely many such $x$. For each $(w,x)$, we create a node in the
lexical order, and then we begin inspecting the various $y$ in
turn, searching for a $z$ for which $R(w,x,y,z)$ (but waiting for
each $y$ to finish before considering the next). Every time we find
that $(w,x)$ admits the next $y$ having such a $z$, then we add
another node to the interval associated with $(w,x)$. Thus, this
$x$ will be an acceptable witness for $w$ if this interval grows
infinitely often, and otherwise it will have only finitely many
points. So $w$ will satisfy the property $\exists x\forall y\exists
z\ R(w,x,y,z)$ if and only if the interval associated with $w$
(ranging over all possible $x$) has order type strictly exceeding
$\omega$, and otherwise it will have order type $\omega$. It
follows from our assumptions on the relation $R$ that this relation
has order type $\omega^3$. But finally, any isomorphism of this
relation to the standard notations for ordinals below $\omega^3$
will tell us the length of the interval associated with $w$. So if
$0''$ could compute the isomorphism, then it could solve the
$\Sigma_3$ relation with which we began, and this is impossible.
Since that relation was $\Sigma_3$-complete, there can be no such
isomorphism computable from $0''$. $\Box$

I believe that these methods can be pushed harder, and one might
expect to prove the optimal results.

Comment: From the way I understand (the confusing wording of) OP's question, they want to know whether the isomorphism belongs to $\mathbf{0}''$ ("Total-computable"), not $\mathbf{0}$.

Comment: You may be right, but I think I can also make a counterexample for that, with a longer order.

Comment: Can you add this to your answer, then?  Even if it's not exactly what OP wanted, it's interesting, and I don't find it obvious.

Comment: At the risk of requiring a transfinite sequence of edits of this answer, I'll conjecture that, given any hyperarithmetical set $A$, there exist two isomorphic, computable well-orderings of $\omega$ such that the isomorphism between them is not computable from $A$. On the other hand, I conjecture that the isomorphism between two computable well-orders of $\omega$ is always hyperarithmetical. (I think there's a result in reverse mathematics saying that comparability of well-orders is equivalent to $\text{ATR}_0$, which  suggests my conjectures.)

Comment: The second conjecture in my previous comment seems to have an easy proof. The isomorphism sends $a$ in the first order to $b$ in the second iff there's an isomorphism between the predecessors of $a$ in the first and the predecessors of $b$ in the second. So the isomorphism is $\Sigma^1_1$. For a $\Pi^1_1$ definition, just say that the $\Sigma^1_1$ definition doesn't hold for $a$ and any $b'\neq b$.

Comment: I posted the $0''$ result, and I believe as Andreas has commented that this can be pushed much further. My argument used basically $\omega^2$, and it seems one can go higher in the arithmetic hierarchy using taller order types. Perhaps one can get this down to $\omega$, but I don't quite see it yet.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Thanks for answer. I will need quite some time to read your answer (so it may take some time marking your answer). Anyway, I think that I can create an example for $\omega$ (without much difficulty) where the isomorphism isn't halt-computable (using bad notation where successor function won't be computable). Beyond that for $\omega$, I don't know much. As for the first conjecture by Andreas Blass, in case true, I think there might be another parameter as to the smallest ordinal (where the isomorphism isn't computable from a given set). Quite beyond my scope though.

Comment: Andreas's conjecture is too strong, since with an oracle for 0' we can identify the not element by recognizing adjacent points. So the order types must go beyond omega.

Comment: *next element..

Comment: 0' can compute isomorphisms for orders up to omega squared, and 0'' up to omega cubed.

Comment: My question/guess was partially motivated by my own "result", which I mentioned in the closed (soon to be deleted) thread. If any user here says that their construction is correct, most likely it is. However, you might still want to briefly check my comment under the original question.

Comment: I'm unsure to which result you refer. Can you state it here? Meanwhile, I've updated my answer to explain things a little more clearly. Let me know if you have any questions. Your conjecture about $0''$ is wrong in light of the counterexample order I give with order-type $\omega^3$, but but it is right for order-types below $\omega^2$, although in that case $0'$ also suffices.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Well most likely your construction would be correct, so forget about it. I do have a question before I start reading though (which would take me quite some time). For the example you have constructed for $\omega^3$ for example, is the function $P{_1}{_2}$ computably unbounded w.r.t. TOTAL-programs (programs with access to oracle for TOTAL).

Comment: I'd have to think about it.

Comment: By the way, there seems to be room in the results I mentioned to improve the last theorem to produce computable relations of type $\omega^3$ that are not isomorphic even allowing oracle $0'''$. This would show the earlier result to be optimal, and I suspect this is the case.

Comment: Perhaps Andreas did not mean well-orderings of *type* $\omega$, but merely well-orderings of a countable set.

Comment: Ah, thanks, in that case, I think he is right! Meanwhile, my updated answer shows that one needs to the order type to increase to form counterexamples as the oracle increases in strength.

Comment: As @RobinSaunders said, I meant well-orderings of $\omega$, not well-orderings of order-type $\omega$.  (Rereading my comments, I see that I got lucky and actually wrote what I meant.)

Comment: "Anyway, I think that I can create an example for $\omega$ (without much difficulty) where the isomorphism isn't halt-computable" .... I posted this in one my previous comments but this is incorrect (as follows trivially from the very first theorem in the answer). I am not removing that comment to avoid unnecessary confusion (w.r.t. flow of conversation).

Comment: Very well-structured answer, I just have trouble with the last theorem. But that's just because it's in more abstract/symbolic form (and hence just shows my own lack of understanding). Though now that I know that this kind of example exists, I am confident enough that I can re-create an example of lack of TOTAL-computable isomorphism (using less abstract form of programs). I think it is somewhat remarkable that the isomorphism function can be made so difficult to dominate (in terms of growth rate).

Comment: Thanks very much, I find the question very interesting. By the way, I think you'll be more readily understood if you refer to the $0''$-computable functions, rather than the TOTAL-computable functions. The issue is that the phrase "total computable function" is commonly used to refer to the functions that are computable (not using any oracle) and total, as opposed to partial. Since Tot is Turing equivalent to $0''$, however, I think most computability theorists would refer to your class of functions as the $0''$-computable functions.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I have a related question that came to my mind. Is there known work regarding which well-orderings are provably not recursive? The second statement of Andreas above in comments can be thought of as a tool in this direction. A simple and specific example: consider the notation $N$ for $\omega$ which happens to be same as natural numbers. Every notation whose isomorphism is recursive with $N$ is trivially recursive. However, clearly there are many notations whose isomorphism with $N$ is $0\,'$-computable yet they are not recursive. Any references for work in this direction?

Comment: @AndreasBlass Perhaps you can also comment if you know some references that consider this kind of question. Also, the example for $\omega$ was just meant as a specific example/case. What I meant was the question in the general sense.

Comment: There is quite a bit of work aimed at the computable ordinals, and much of it is wrapped up with set theory, particularly admissible set theory, and the study of the hyperarithmetic sets, since the computable ordinals turn out to be the same as the hyperarithmetically definable ordinals, and $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$ is a model of Kripke-Platek set theory. So the keywords would be: hyperarithmetic, admissible set theory, KP, Churck-Kleene ordinal.